# Load address on a bootstrap modal for editing address reactJs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, bootstrap-4, mern

I have a component called EditAddress in which I want that on a button click a bootstrap modal must open with address details pefilled on the modal.
Suppose I have 5 address and the user click on the edit button corresponding to the 2nd address then the second address must load on the bootstrap modal. I have written a few lines of code for it but the problem is on the first click on the edit button corresponding to any address by default state is loading then on the second click everything is working normally for that address.

[image]

This is my code for the component.

```
import React, { useContext, useState } from 'react'
import { API } from './backend';
import { userContext } from './contexts/userContext'

const EditAddress = ({index}) => {

  console.log("component rerendered")
  const [values,setValues] = useState({
    name:"",
    address:"",
    state:"",
    pincode:"",
    phonenumber:""
  })

  const {name,address,state,pincode,phonenumber} = values;
  const {user,setUser} = useContext(userContext);
  // const [toggle,setToggle]= useState(false);

  let _id;
  

  const addressFill = async () => {
       
    console.log(user);
    const addressArr = await user.address;
    console.log(values);

    setValues({
      name:addressArr[index].name,
      address:addressArr[index].address,
      state:addressArr[index].state,
      pincode:addressArr[index].pincode,
      phonenumber:addressArr[index].phonenumber
    })

     
    

    document.getElementById('name').value = name;
    document.getElementById('address').value = address;
    document.getElementById('state').value = state;
    document.getElementById('pincode').value = pincode;
    document.getElementById('phonenumber').value = phonenumber;

    
    

    console.log(values);

  }

  if(user){
    _id = user._id;
  }


  const handleChange = (event,name)=>{
    setValues({...values,[name]: event.target.value})
    //[name] object can't be key variable that's why we use this syntax

  } 

  const handleSubmit = async()=>{
     
    try{ 
     const middle = await fetch(`${API}/address/add`,{
       method:'PUT',
       headers:{
         Accept:'application/json',
         "content-type":'application/json'
       },
       body:JSON.stringify({
         _id,
        address:values        
       })
     })
 
     const response = await middle.json();
 
 
        setUser(response)
        setValues({ name:"",
        address:"",
        state:"",
        pincode:"",
        phonenumber:""})
 
     console.log(response);
    }
    catch(error)
    {
       console.log(error);
    }
 
 }

const form = ()=>{
 return  <form>
<div className="form-group">
<label for="exampleInputEmail1"><b>Full name (First and Last name)</b></label>
  <input type="text" className="form-control" value={name} id="name" aria-describedby="emailHelp" onChange={(e)=>handleChange(e,"name")}/>
</div>
<div className="form-group">
<label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1"><b>Address Details</b></label>
  <textarea type='' className="form-control" value={address} id="address" placeholder="Apartment,unit,building,floor,etc."  onChange={(e)=>handleChange(e,"address")}></textarea>
</div>

<div className="form-group">
<label for="exampleInputEmail1"><b>State / Province / Region</b></label>
  <input type="text" className="form-control" value={state} id="state" aria-describedby="emailHelp"  onChange={(e)=>handleChange(e,"state")}/>
</div>

<div className="form-group">
  <div className='row'>
     <div className='col-sm-6'>
     <label for="exampleInputEmail1"><b>PIN Code</b></label>
     <input type="number" className="form-control" value={pincode} id="pincode" aria-describedby="emailHelp"  onChange={(e)=>handleChange(e,"pincode")}/>
     </div>
     <div className='col-sm-6'>
     <label for="exampleInputEmail1"><b>Phone number</b></label>
     <input type="number" className="form-control" value={phonenumber} id="phonenumber" aria-describedby="emailHelp"  onChange={(e)=>handleChange(e,"phonenumber")}/>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>

</form>
}

  return (
    <>
    <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary ml-1"  id = "editAddress" onClick = {addressFill} data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editModal">
      Edit address 
    </button>

<div className="modal fade" id="editModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" >
<div className="modal-dialog" role="document">
  <div className="modal-content" >
    <div className="modal-header bg-warning">
      <h5 className="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Enter Address </h5>
      <button type="button" className="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div className="modal-body">
     {form()}
    </div>
    <div className="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" className="btn btn-primary" onClick={handleSubmit}>Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</> 
  )
}

export default EditAddress
```

Kindly help me resolving my issue .

For a particular address on first click on editaddress button loads my by default state then , corresponding clicks are working fine.